# Subnetwork and Subnet Mask

Tags: networking, network-programming, subnet, private-subnet

Block - **130.0.0.0/25** .
Want to create **8** subnet.

> Binary Form of Block will be
>   1000 0010.0000 0000.0000 0000.0000 0000/25
>
> Subnet mask would be
>   1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1000 0000

How will I make 8 subnetwork out of this?

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) for a complete description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `2 ^ 7 = 128` IP's (binary form: 000 0000 - 111 1111). Each subnetwork will have `128 / 8 = 16` IP's. So the subnetworks will look as follows.

1. 130.0.0.0 - 130.0.0.15
2. 130.0.0.16 - 130.0.0.31
3. 130.0.0.32 - 130.0.0.47
4. 130.0.0.48 - 130.0.0.63
5. 130.0.0.64 - 130.0.0.79
6. 130.0.0.80 - 130.0.0.95
7. 130.0.0.96 - 130.0.0.111
8. 130.0.0.112 - 130.0.0.127

Comment: Thankyou very much ..!! I hope u have a great day !!